# Who is the Rabbid behind Rabbid Rosalina in this image from the Mario + Rabbids Sparks of Hope second DLC trailer?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-sparks-of-hope

In teaser trailer of Mario + Rabbids Sparks of Hope's 2nd DLC, I saw a pair of rabbid ears behind Rabbid Rosalina.

[image]

I swear it's not Edge, but who is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its an actual Rabbid (at least not an actual, *physically present* rabbid). I think it's a decorative bobblehead like figurine that is on the desk behind Rabbid Rosalina.

I am guessing you watched [this trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6ZNDWho3-k), which if you watch a little further, shows a different angle of the room briefly:

[image: figurine circled]

I circled what I think you/we are seeing.  If you look real close during the clip, you can kind of see it sway like a bobble head does, or actually I think its more like one of those [Hawaiian Hula figurines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6EF4.png) that people mount on their dashboards in cars, which I think is what this decorative object is mimicking.  It's also right next to that cup with the straw in it, which you can see in both screenshots.

Comment: I remembered. After i complete the game 100%, i saw menu and also rabbid doll (that thing you said) is right next to cup with straw.